# Steps for upgrading Eclipse Android project

Tags: android

My Eclipse Android project was created using Android-19 SDK. I now see that Android-20 is available.

What is the proper way to upgrade my existing project to Android-20? Regards.

Comment: I would just change the target to 20 if you want to target the next API level.  Unless you really want to take advantage of new features that are only available in the latest release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your manifest to include the new API level. Then open up the project properties, navigate to "Android", check the desired project build target, and then click OK. In Package Explorer, you should then see a change to the Android library version being used for the project builds.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In summary, 1) change AndroidManifest.xml file's targetSdkVersion and 2) change project.properties file's target property. Don't I need to replace android-support-v4.jar as well?

Comment: @Peter - I don't believe so. That library is designed to work for any build target from level 4 up.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select Project / Properties / Android option and choose an Android Build Target. For your question select api level 20.
2. Update your projects manifest file, set target to api level you want. For your question:

   android:targetSdkVersion="20"

**Note:** Allways be carefull while using new features of new api levels. Control them programmatically to prevent method not found exceptions on devices which have lower api levels.

For instance;

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 20) {
   // Here, use only only methods for api level 20+ devices 
} else {
   // Alternative methods which are supported by all devices
}
```